# Placing contents of an IF statement into the next IF statement?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm attempting to place the first IF statement below (a [TCPDF barcode](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a4816d61822a4bad6e35bb441c1699aab)) into the content of the next IF statement. This should place the barcode right before the break (above the title key).

Whenever `$content` is called inside of `$rset_html`, it displays the specified key in the IF statement.

```
if($key == 'field_cinfo_zip_1') {
    $rset_html .= $view->pdf->write1DBarcode('01234567094987654321-'.str_replace("-","",$content), 'IMB', '', '', '', 0.1, 0.01, $barstyle, '');
}
```

How to put this IF statement above into `<CONTENTS OF IF STATEMENT ABOVE HERE>` below?

```
if ($key == 'title'){
    $rset_html .= <CONTENTS OF IF STATEMENT ABOVE HERE>."<br>$content";
}
```

Though this seems very basic, I don't know how easy this really is. I might have to figure out how to call fields without using IF statements and the $rset_html variable, but have no idea how that can be done.

Comment: (How to do this without nesting IF statements). Nesting IF statements will not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

would this suit your needs?

```
    if($key == 'field_cinfo_zip_1') {
        $rset_html .= $view->pdf->write1DBarcode('01234567094987654321-'.str_replace("-","",$content), 'IMB', '', '', '', 0.1, 0.01, $barstyle, '');
    } 

    if ($key == 'title'){
        $rset_html .= $rset_html."<br>$content";
    }
```

Comment: TCPDF doesn't seem to like that: http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/9198/pdfbarcodeerror.png

Comment: In fact, the only way I have found to rid myself of this error thus far, is to put `$view->pdf->AddPage();` before the write1DBarcode line. Here is a better explanation: http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/553/tcpdfissueexplanation.png

Comment: See line 200, here is my raw code: http://matt.mw/junk/php/views_pdf_plugin_row_fields.inc

Comment: were you getting that same error before or is that something that only shows up when you move $rset_html?

Comment: I haven't been able to render barcodes without adding in the AddPage function directly above it yet. I don't know what is causing the vague error in Adobe Reader. Any help would be very appreciated and I'll compensate anyone for their time.

Comment: Update: Looks like the libraries had to be updated. Views PDF the Drupal module comes with an older version of the libraries. Ever since I've updated the libraries, there is no Adobe Reader error.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Looks like the libraries had to be updated. Views PDF the Drupal module comes with an older version of the libraries. Ever since I've updated the libraries, there is no further Adobe Reader errors.